# Accessing DataBases from different servers

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a network of websites hosted on two different servers, server1 and server2.
I need to be able to access the data stored in a MySQL DataBase on server1 from a PHP script in a site hosted on server2.

Say a user registers on site1 on server1 and his data is inserted into the DataBase on server1. Now, that user would be able to log in on site2 on server2 with the same registration.
That would mean the PHP script on server2 needs access to the MySQL DB on server1. I don't want to copy the user data over to a DB on server2, because the user might also edit his or her user information on site1.

I'd like to be able to share this data without editing the server's data (as in http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).
So far, I haven't been able to figure out a secure way of achieving this, does anyone know how to do this using PHP (or JavaScript, but I'd prefer the system to work for everyone, regardless if JS is enabled)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by allowing your other servers hostname to connect to your database.

In a MySQL command prompt or phpmyadmin execute the query:

`GRANT ALL ON databasename.* TO username@'ipaddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';`

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Please summarize up/cite the relevant information and put it here as well. Links break and having to visit a link to see an answer is annoying.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! But I'm not sure if I can apply this right now, as I don't have direct access to my server... is there a sort fo work-around to this problem that doesn't require editing server data?

Answer (score 1):

On server1 the script1 looks something like this:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user="dbuser";
$pass="dbpw";
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
```

and on server2 the script2 looks something like:

```
$host = "server1.domain.com";
$user="dbuser";
$pass="dbpw";
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
```

So you just have to enter a different host name to connect to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! I already tried this, but remote access to MySQL database server is disabled for security reasons, as is default. Doing this would require first to apply @Tar's answer. My question was for a sort of a work-around - if at all possible without modifying MySQL server data...