# Can you change domain name without changing database wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website that I used as my testing website. Now the client bought a hosting package that has no database. The idea now is to change the old URL of the testing site to a new domain name which the client bought. Can I transfer that new domain name to the old website and as well as change sub-pages but without a database? Please help me!!!!
Please!!!

Comment: I dont think it is possible. You cannot access database from another server. Just make the client know that the database is required for the working of the site.

Comment: or check down the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860897/accessing-databases-from-different-servers#answers. But I cant say if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks I've just done that

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand the question.

Do you want to move the WP installation to a server without a DB? That won't work...

If you want to point the new domain to your server, go ahead and do that, afterwards change the domain settings in the WP admin. You might also have to change the wp-config, not 100% sure on that one.

But honestly, just tell your client that to buy a new server with the specs you give him. PHP version, DB etc. You are the expert not him.