# Placing database on one host and PHP files on another

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I'm trying to figure out *if* and how I can run PHP files on one host (ie: Hostgator) and run the database on a separate host (ie: Godaddy).

I have cPanel Linux plans for both and want to do this as a privacy and security measure, so no one host has all my data. I cannot currently run my own servers so please don't suggest that.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes its possible. I dont see any benefit to it though - if you dont trust your host not to rip you off, you need to move host.

Comment: You may find that your shared hosts do not permit external connections to their MySQL servers. However some may if you ask them - you'll need to ask tech support for these two companies to find out. If one permits external connections and the other does not, that will reveal which one becomes the database host and the other is the web host.

Comment: Is any host really trustworthy now-a-days. They are just the wizard behind the curtain...

Comment: I'd say a good number of hosts are trustworthy, but don't choose cowboys. There are a lot of very cheap and inexperienced hosts - use ones that have been the business for a long time, or who have a good brand name.

Comment: Some unsavory hosts...RE-SELL...your code and db to INQUIRERS...one that begins with a G, has been doing this for YEARS. The buyer than just regimmicks ur material and its easy street no coding and not much editing needed...

Comment: Someone's tin foil hat is a bit too snug.

Comment: I dont wear tin foil, i use it to freeze meat, over the air seal bags.. thanks for playing.

Comment: But if you want to trust everyone, do so at your own peril.

Comment: I would doubt GoDaddy are selling people's intellectual property - far too risky as a business strategy. They have [enough reputation problems](http://mashable.com/2012/09/10/godaddy-gone-recover-its-reputation/) as it is, and as a large consumer-facing host, they aren't an expert's choice - they will have a large support bill and won't be able to invest in high quality staff or infrastructure in the way that, say, Digital Ocean can.

Comment: u said godaddy not me lol    its not hard... u just re-scheme the colors and look and ur on free street...

Comment: (Some general points: we tend to discourage "text speak" here, as it doesn't sit well with the professional tone of the site; it annoys some people to the degree that it can attract downvotes. Also, if you reply to me, you need to use my handle - @halfer - so I get a notification).

Comment: There are lots of (legitimate) complaints about GoDaddy. I can find not evidence at all that anyone has ever reported them stealing peoples code.

Comment: @halfer Points noted, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing DataBases from different servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860897/accessing-databases-from-different-servers)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible. When you make the database connection, you need to tell PHP *where* the database is. This defaults to "this machine", but you can feed it an IP and it will connect there.

The target is given to the construct function of whatever `connect` function you are using.

If you are using an existing piece of software, then whether or not this is possible depends on the software in question, but most will have support for it.

Comment: So its as easy as editing config file or what have you ---- to where address db is ?

Comment: It should be, yes. Most software have a host_name setting somewhere in the config, if you point that to another machine then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you set up a connection string in PHP for a database, it typically includes something called the **hostname** which is how you would connect to a remote database. This is pretty standard industry practice (I have some experience with this) though it has more to do with performance then security.

Comment: Yes, i see your point on speed. But, understand some hosts will just take your code and run similar sites, i used to work for many major hosting compnay and they just sell your code inquirers that like your site. As you can imagine would be quite an easy thing to do because u never have physical contact with your host, so you never know what the wizard behind the curtain is doing. A shame for sure.

Comment: The protection against this isn't splitting things into two groups, it's filing a trademark if you have code you want to protect and pursuing legal action if that is what you think is happening. I have never heard of a hosting company doing that (at least here in the United States). The problem with the approach you are suggesting (for security) is that a decent developer could very easily reverse engineer your database from just the code, so isolating it is not protecting your code from someone stealing it and reusing it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it's conceivably possible to run your web server at hosting provider A and your MySQL instance at hosting provider B.

**When you get this working,** your MySQL queries will travel, most likely unencrypted, over the public network between the two providers. A typical CMS web app (Joomla!, WordPress, etc) makes at least ten MySQL queries to get the information to render each page. So you'll have a bunch of long distance query round trips, and latency will suffer.

Now maybe the two providers in question have a high-speed private route between them, but it strikes me as unlikely.

**Why unencrypted?** For profitability at the typical shared-hosting provider, it's important to put as many customers as possible on each server. The transport layer security code necessary to handle encrypted connections from clients adds server overhead. It also requires server crypto-certificate administration. You can tell whether your MySQL supports encrypted connections with this command.

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';
```

Both providers I use reply "DISABLED" to this query.

**To get it working**, you're going to have to persuade provider B to whitelist (authorize) MySQL connections from the IP address range at provider A.  Some providers let you whitelist MySQL connections from your personal machines, others don't. This whitelisting is a risky business: you share the MySQL server with other customers of provider B. When an external address is whitelisted, there's a risk of cheesy denial-of-service attacks to all those shared customers.

So, ask provider B's support person if they'll whitelist provider A for MySQL connections. And don't be surprised if they say it's against their security policy to do that.

Comment: Wouldn't it still using the host its calling from... their tunnel to reach the new desitination...

Answer (score 0):

In short:

> Is it possible?  **Yes**
>
> Is it efficient? **No**

No in this case, because you are putting the servers far away from each other. This is practically good when you have the application server and database server either on the same network or near each other for better performance and security. Now you can practically open the database for vulnerability and a thousand other issues with performance and security.

Comment: should i just bite the bullet and use windows server and plesk and two desks lol

Comment: @SuperGrid are you sure you tried to make a point here?